# What would be the most efficient way to iterate over two different models in django project

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django website. I am having a products page in my templates in which there are multiple categories and there are multiple products under each category.
These are my models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    type=models.CharField(max_length=30)
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    productid=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and this is my current view.py:

```
def category(request,sort):
    b=""
    if sort=="all":
        b="timeadded"
    elif sort=="new":
        b="-timeadded"
    context = {
         
        'types' : Category.objects.all(),
        'prods': Product.objects.filter().order_by(b),
        'cartItems':[],
   
    }
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer=request.user.customer
        order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        cartItems=order.get_cart_items,     
        items=order.orderitem_set.all()
        context['list_cart'] = order.orderitem_set.values_list('product__id', flat=True)    
    return render(request,"category.html",context)
```

This view takes care of whether the product is already in customers cart or not. Currently to show these products I was iterating like this:

```
{% for type in types %}
{% for product in prods %}
{% if product.type.id == type.id %}}
//Display the details
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Initially this was working fine for me when I hadnt added many products but now when I was testing with around ~400 products it is loading up very slowly.The reason might be that I am iterating over all products for all categories. Please tell me a more efficient way to work this up which also keeps in mind  whether the product is in cart or not and also how to iterate in my template.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fdirst fdetch all the `Product`s, and then group these by type, for example:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

def category(request,sort):
    sorting = ['category_id']
    if sort == 'all':
        sorting.append('timeadded')
    elif sort == 'new':
        sorting.append('-timeadded')
    qs = Product.objects.select_related('category').order_by(*sorting)
    types = [
        (k, list(vs))
        for k, vs in groupby(qs, attrgetter('category'))
    ]
    context = {
        'types' : types,
        'cartItems':[],
    }
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer=request.user.customer
        order, created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        cartItems=order.get_cart_items,     
        items=order.orderitem_set.all()
        context['list_cart'] = order.orderitem_set.values_list('product__id', flat=True)    
    return render(request,"category.html",context)
```

In the template, we then can iterate over the key-value tuples:

```
{% for category, prods in types %}
    <b>{{ category.type }}</b>
    {% for product in prods %}
        {{ product.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to work absolutely fine but I had some doubts. What does sorting=['category_id'] do. Even if parameter is anything it loads up the site which didnt happen earlier. Also the most important question will your answer affect any other functionality like products in cart or not. Also as I am a beginner I am looking some methods in your answer for first time so can u briefly explain how is it more efficient then my way.Thanks

Comment: @VATSALJAIN: it is a list of ordering conditions. We first need to order on the `category_id` (or something of the category) to prevent getting the `Product`s in an order where they do not make "sequences" of `Product`s with the same category.

Comment: I eddited my comment . Please look to it. Thanks

Comment: @VATSALJAIN: normally it will not alter the cart functionality, since that is normally different logic. The performance gain depends on the number of categories, since it turns an *O(nm)* algorithm in an *O(n)* one.

Comment: That went above my head. Are you implying that It would not require to go over all the products to check if the product.category.id == type.id

Comment: @VATSALJAIN: yes, we scan the list of `Product`s only *once*, and the `groupby`, will make items for each subsequence of `Product`s that have the same category.

Comment: Ok thanks. I hope it works exactly the same it was working with my code but more efficiently